# Eslint: "jsx-a11y/label-has-for" is invalid

Tags: eslint

In WebStorm, I cannot get rid of this error:

```
Error: /Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint-config-rallycoding/rules/react-a11y.js:
    Configuration for rule "jsx-a11y/label-has-for" is invalid:
    Value ["label"] should be object.

Referenced from: /Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint-config-rallycoding/index.js
Referenced from: /Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/.eslintrc

Error: /Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint-config-rallycoding/rules/react-a11y.js:
    Configuration for rule "jsx-a11y/label-has-for" is invalid:
    Value ["label"] should be object.

Referenced from: /Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint-config-rallycoding/index.js
Referenced from: /Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/.eslintrc
    at validateRuleOptions (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:115:15)
    at Object.keys.forEach.id (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:155:9)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validateRules (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:154:30)
    at Object.validate (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:232:5)
    at loadFromDisk (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:507:19)
    at load (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:550:20)
    at configExtends.reduceRight (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:421:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (<anonymous>)
    at applyExtends (/Users/kamiranoff/dev/myApp/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:403:28)
```

I did try to override the local `.eslintrc` with:

```
{
  "extends": "rallycoding",
  "rules": {
    "arrow-body-style": 0,
    "quote-props": 0,
    "global-require": 0,
    "max-len": [
      "error",
      120
    ],
    "react/require-extension": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true,
    "fetch": true,
    "Headers": true,
    "Request": true
  }
}
```

And setting up the WebStorm config (I just change the folder name for privacy):
[image]

And on my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "as": "0.4.1",
    "axios": "0.16.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.8.5",
    "contentful": "4.6.4",
    "eil-cid": "~1.0.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "listify": "1.0.0",
    "localytics-react-native": "2.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.5",
    "lottie-react-native": "2.2.7",
    "moment": "2.19.3",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.14",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-add-calendar-event": "0.3.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.9.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "0.9.0",
    "react-native-config": "0.8.1",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-fabric": "0.5.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "2.2.3",
    "react-native-i18n": "2.0.9",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.5.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "1.1.462",
    "react-native-picker": "4.3.5",
    "react-native-showmedia": "file:packages/react-native-showmedia",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.5.13",
    "react-native-timeline-listview": "0.2.2",
    "react-native-triangle": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-webview-bridge": "github:EurostarDigital/react-native-webview-bridge",
    "react-native-wkwebview-reborn": "1.10.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "4.10.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "tai-password-strength": "1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.2",
    "codecov": "3.0.0",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eil-content": "~2.2.2",
    "enzyme": "3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.1.1",
    "eslint": "4.11.0",
    "google-spreadsheet": "2.0.4",
    "husky": "0.14.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "4.0.0",
    "prettier": "~1.8.2",
    "react-native-mock": "0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./config/testEnvironment.js"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "gitDir": "./",
    "*.js": [
      "prettier --single-quote --print-width 120 --tab-width 2 --write",
      "./node_modules/eslint-config-rallycoding/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
```

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: looks similar to https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/348. What is your `eslint-config-rallycoding` version?

Comment: inside of the node_modules I have this: ` 'jsx-a11y/label-has-for': [2, ['label']],`

Comment: I saw the github issue, but did not fix it for me. like if .eslintrc was not overriding the other settings.

Comment: please provide your package.json

Comment: Sure, I added my package.json

Comment: disabling `"jsx-a11y/label-has-for"` in `.eslintrc` doesn't indeed work; to get rid of the issue, you have to downgrade `"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y"` to make it compatible with `"eslint-config-rallycoding"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not specific to Webstorm, you will see the same errors when running *EsLint* in terminal. The problem is that `"eslint-config-rallycoding"` doesn't yet support v6.x of `"jsx-a11y/label-has-for"` plugin. You should probably file an issue to https://github.com/StephenGrider/ESLint-Rallycoding/issues on this.

The only way to get rid of the issue is downgrading both `"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y"` and `"eslint"`, like:

```
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
...
"eslint": "^3.19.0",
```

see https://github.com/sweth/react-native-udemy/commit/2dd74ca887e8b32b82ee1e37e5a290edaa657b82

Comment: Thanks. I downgraded for now but try to open an issue.